# How to sum all values in the std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

How to sum all values in `std::map<std::string, size_t>` collection without using for loop? The map resides as private member in a class. Accumulation is performed in public function call.

I do not want to use boost or other 3rd parties.

Comment: I'd like to swim the atlantic without getting in the water? Or do you just want to avoid writing the for loop yourself?

Comment: I'm looking LINQ like functions as in C#

Comment: They use loops, it's just not so evident.

Comment: I know behind the scenes is the loop. I want to use shortcut with just one line of code

Comment: Why is this question closed as not constructive? It's a good question.

Comment: Lol why is this closed, the question is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this with a lambda and `std::accumulate`. Note you need an up to date compiler (at least MSVC 2010, Clang 3.1 or GCC 4.6):

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
    
int main()
{
    const std::map<std::string, std::size_t> bla = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 3}};
    const std::size_t result = std::accumulate(
        std::begin(bla),
        std::end(bla),
        0, // initial value of the sum
        [](const std::size_t previous, const std::pair<const std::string, std::size_t>& p)
        { return previous + p.second; }
    );
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

[Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b41182c6ab4f1541).

If you use C++14, you can improve the readability of the lambda by using a generic lambda instead:

```
[](const std::size_t previous, const auto& element)
{ return previous + element.second; }
```

Comment: #include <numeric> is missing

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy fixed. GCC didn't catch that, thanks.

Comment: Great example for introducing lambdas !

Comment: For those trying to shorten the function call, try `std::accumulate(bla.begin(), bla.end(), 0, [](const size_t previous, decltype(*bla.begin()) p) { return previous+p.second; });`.

Answer (score 5):

Use std::accumulate. But it very likely will use loop behind the scenes.

Comment: how to use it? can you provide code sample?

Comment: No. I have to feed my children now. Look for 4 parameter version.

Comment: Do you want your post to be marked as answer? I do not want to declare additional function to the 4th parameter and use some inline binding

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy then use a lambda.

Comment: sure :) @BillyONeal did not know how to use lambda

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy you don't need to use a lambda anyway; a local-struct-functor would work equally well and does not need the std c++0x restriction.

Comment: @WhozCraig local struct functor will NOT work with c++03 and older. You need C++11 for that (local types cannot be used with templates).

Comment: @Tomek Thanks. If it *did* work with an 03-implementation, I assume it must be vendor-supported then, as it apparently isn't standard ? (I ask because I've used it in the past, before C++11 was near finished without problems, but only on one specific platform, never tried others. Thanks.